# Change the lens unit for viewport

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I found FoV is much easier to understand than lens length. For a camera I can set the display unit as such:

[image]

It's all good. Except I failed to find the corresponding option for the viewport:

[image]

Is it possible to show the viewport's FoV just like the camera's?

Comment: Hello :). This is a very good observation. It seems the viewport camera is stuck at milimeters. However, that doesn't make much sense, since you cannot even change the sensor size there...